# Type 'undefined[]' is missing the following properties from type

Tags: angular, component

Mi interfaz:

```js
export interface GuidelineRSC {
  [x: string]: any;
  id: number;
  code: string;
  composedCode: string;
  name: string;
  type: number;
  source: string;
  level: string;
  importance_level: string;
}
```

Uso / llamado de mi interfaz en mi componente

```js
  recomendedDocs: GuidelineRSC = [];
  selectedArray = [];
  selectedData = [];
  form: FormGroup;
  isVisible = true;
  tcText = tcText;
```

Me salta el error Type 'undefined[]' is missing the following properties from type GuidelineRSC, alguien sabe como puedo solucionar este error? o si estoy llamando mal a la interfaz en mi componente?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás asignando un array vacío a una variable de tipo **GuidelineRSC** no de tipo **array de GuidelineRSC**. Debes declararla así

```
recomendedDocs: GuidelineRSC[] = [];
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, revisé tu perfil, no se si de pronto en ese curso de angular tengas algun tema relacionado a esto para poder aprender mas. Muchas gracias de nuevo y espero que tengas un buen día

Comment: Hola @SantiagoSanchezCorrea. Lo cierto es que tu duda es más de Typescript que de Angular. Por lo tanto, no trato ese tema específicamente, aunque sí aparece en alguno de los ejemplos. Me alegro de haberte ayudado.